# How to blur and transparant only background and not content in jgrowl notification

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jgrowl

i tried blur and transparant jgrowl notification background, but just transparant works. when blur the content also blur. content mean text notification. i wan't background transparant and blur and not content.
[THIS jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fcL3mx7b/1/)

CSS:

```
.test{
background-color:rgba(102, 204, 153,0.95);
color:#fff;
font-weight:bold;
border:1px #fff solid;
filter: blur(5px) ;
}
```

JGROWL :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $.jGrowl("<p class='upper'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle' aria-hidden='true'></i> <?=$row['NTFY_TTL'];?></p><?=$row['NTFY_DESC'];?><br> <small>Posted <?=$row['BEG_DT'];?></small>", { 
        theme: 'test',
        position: 'top-right',
        life: 3000 
    });
    });
</script>
```

[THIS jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fcL3mx7b/1/)

Comment: JSfiddle please

Comment: i update and add THIS jsfiddle above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a better way but alternatively can be done with the help of empty div Please check required browser compatibility before implementation

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fcL3mx7b/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">
<span class="test2">

  </span>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quod atque ipsam cupiditate eum, debitis illo repudiandae aperiam dolorum quae neque praesentium, quis vero iure distinctio natus quisquam consequuntur officiis.



</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test {
    position: relative;  
    z-index: 10;
}

.test2{
    background-color:rgba(102, 204, 153,0.95);
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px #fff solid;
    filter: blur(5px) ;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: but the output different like what u give.. see THIS jsfiddle link . i update above

Comment: Please check - https://jsfiddle.net/fcL3mx7b/2/ are you looking for this

Comment: yea, in my web just like that. still have little black in background. i want not black anymore.